# AngularJS ng-repeat through multiple arrays of same JSON object

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can I iterate throught two different arrays of same object in AngularJS 1.6?

What I mean:

JS:

```
var foo = {
   names: ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"],
   surnames: ["Surname1", "Surname2", "Surname3"] 
}
```

In my HTML part I would like to do something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="name in foo.names, surname in foo.surnames">
    <li><span>{{name}}</span> <span>{{surname}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

The result I'd like to get is:

Name1 Surname1

Name2 Surname2

Name3 Surname3

Is there a way?

Comment: In one ng-repeat you can iterate one array. You can use nested ng-repeat .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work.

```
<ul ng-repeat="name in foo.names">
    <li><span>{{name}}</span> <span>{{foo.surnames[$index]}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the first array `$index` to access the second array elements

```
<ul ng-repeat="name in foo.names">
    <li><span>{{name}}</span> <span>{{foo.surnames[$index]}}</span></li>
</ul>
```